# square bracket notation (not referring to object access!)

Tags: javascript

i was digging throug some code (async module for nodejs) and ran into the following notation:

```
return fn.apply(null, [async.forEachSeries].concat(args));
```

if seen this notation using the square brackets alot, but have no idea whoat it means exactly.
is this related to ES5?

greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really quite simple. You are basically gluing two arrays together and passing the resulting array as second argument to apply. See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

e.g.:

```
// this should clarify
console.log([1, 2, 3].concat([4, 5]));
```

Comment: wow okay, of course i know the array literal, but did not realize that it's just the same straigt forward....i feel kind of stupid now. so the code above is basically the same as writing `args.unshift(async.forEachSeries); return fn.apply(null, args);` right?

Answer (score 1):

The expression `[async.forEachSeries]` puts the property `forEachSeries` into an array, then joins this array with the `args` array.

Answer (score 0):

It's a list. You can do:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

To get a list in JavaScript, and `concat` is a list method.

Answer (score 0):

It's a notation for array literals. The following code will create an array with 4 elements:

```
var x = [1, 4, 9, 16];
```

An array is itself an object and has methods like [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to join two arrays and create a new array.